# configure: error: X Window system libraries and header files are required

Tags: 18.04, compiling, ubuntu-mate

I am trying to compile thunar 1.8.4.

It is giving me this error.

```
configure: error: X Window system libraries and header files are required
```

Ubuntu Mate 18.04

Comment: Did you install the dependencies listed in the `README`? I would have expected X Window development files to have been installed as dependencies of the required GTK+ development package

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to install all dependencies of Thunar manually.
You should use the power of APT to get the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep thunar
```

along with new dependencies of [the 1.8.4-1 source code package for upcoming *disco*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/disco/thunar):

```
sudo apt-get install libexo-2-dev libgtk-3-dev libxfce4panel-2.0-dev libxfce4ui-2-dev
```

and then compile and install it with [`checkinstall make install`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware#Installing_the_Package).